# Objective-C Protocol Method Name with 'To' Mangling in Swift 4

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a .framework that I build in Objective-C and I use it in iPhone project built using Swift 4. The .framework uses a delegate to call methods as required.

I've noticed that depending on whether I use the word 'To' in my protocol method signature I get a very different implementation in Swift. For example if I define my protocol methods as:

```
- (void)myApiExited:(Api*)api;
- (void)myApiReadyToPresentViewController:(Api*)api;
```

Then in my Swift project I get:

```
func myApiExited(_ api:XPINApi!) {}

func myApiReady(toPresentViewController api: Api!) {}
```

If however I change the method signature to not include the word 'To' then the method name in the implementation becomes what I would expect it to be:

```
- (void)myApiReadyPresentViewController:(Api*)api;
```

Result:

```
func myApiReadyPresentViewController(_ api: Api!) {}
```

It is very strange to me that the word 'To' would cause this. I expect the method name in my implementation to be the same as in the protocol. Am I doing something that is wrong or is this some kind of bug.

Comment: It's by Apple design, following Swift naming conventions.

Comment: So am I following a naming convention incorrectly or is it normal to expect this?

Comment: I think it's normal to expect this. If I'm not mistaken, there is this complex document describing this naming behavior starting with Swift 3: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md. It may have evolved a bit with Swift 4.x, but not too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design, as the Objective-C importer picks up on conventions in Objective-C names to provide more adapted Swift names. I can't find the exhaustive set of rules, but if you want to specify a Swift name, you can use `NS_SWIFT_NAME`. Off the top of my head, you'd write this:

```
- (void)myApiReadyToPresentViewController:(Api*)api
        NS_SWIFT_NAME(myApiReadyToPresentViewController(_:));
```